# $m \times m$ square and its inscribed rectangles

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine a square with square units covering the entire area of the square. Let $k_m$ represent the total number of rectangles of this $m \times m$ square. There exists a pattern I'll show in a moment where $k_1=1, k_2=9, k_3=36, k_4=100...$. The goal is to solve for any $k_m$.

The difference between, or jump from $k_m$ to $k_{m+1}$ is always $(m+1)^3$. Let's call this jump $r_m$. I made a brief table showing this

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline m \times m
 &  \ r_m & k_m & \Delta k_m \\ \hline
 1 \times 1 & 8 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
 2 \times 2 & 27 & 9 & 8 \\ \hline
3 \times 3 & 64 & 36 & 27 \\ \hline \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\hline 
\end{array}

What I gather from this table is that

\begin{align*} \Delta k_m &= k_m-k_{m-1} \\ k_m &= \Delta k_m+k_{m-1} \\ k_m &= r_{m-1}+k_{m-1}  \\ \implies r_{m-1} & = \Delta k_m\end{align*}

But none of these help me find say, $k_{10}$ without already knowing $k_9$. I know that $1^3+2^3+...+(m+1)^3=k_m$, but this isn't really a solution I'm interested in. I also know that if we're only taking rectangles, then each rectangle has 2 horizontal lines and 2 vertical lines in the square. So given the dimensions, we can say $k_m=[{m\choose2}]^2$, but this, too, doesn't interest me much. I guess what I'm really looking for is a way to solve for $k_m$ with respect to only $r_m$. My closest attempt at this is $$\underbrace{k_m}_{\text{as n $\rightarrow m$}}=\biggr[(n+1)^3+1^2\biggr]+\biggr[(n+2)^3+3^2\biggr]+\biggr[(n+3)^3+6^2\biggr]+\biggr[(n+4)^3+10^2\biggr]+\dots$$

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about. How to express $k_m$ in terms of $r_m$?

Comment: I want to express it without using a summation I'd have to tediously compute for, especially with large values of m. Some expression I can just plug in the value m and get the solution I need using $r_m$ as the independent variable

Comment: $k_m$ is the square of the $m$th triangular number. Does that help?

Comment: Why don't you like the expression $\binom{m+1}2^2$?

Comment: I guess because it seems so obvious. I want to see if there's a solution that's more creative.

Comment: Could you explain this on the example of $1+1$: what answer will be more creative than $2$?

Comment: There aren't many meaningful avenues to get the answer 2. I'm also not asking for a difference answer, I'm asking for an abstract way to get the same answer.

Comment: I find your idea about counting the lines both simple and smart way to obtain the answer. On the other hand I see no clear idea behind the claim $\Delta k_m=m^3$. Why should one start with this one?